# SQL limit, ordering and joins in nested queries

Tags: sql

i have this query:

```
Select VENDOR, CODE, TABOF.OFID,DATEI,DATEF,VARR,VARRT,DESEXT
from (
        Select A_IND,A_COD,A_DES,A_FX,A_ML,
               OFID,DATEI,DATEF,VARR,VARRT,FLAGD,VENDOR
        from ANTAB
        join TABOF
            on (ANTAB.A_COD = TABOF.VENDOR) 
            where
                A_FX <> '' and A_ML <> '' and 
                A_DES <> '' and A_COD <> '' and
                A_IND <> '' and
                A_FX < (47.7 + 0.5) and
                A_FX > (47.7 - 0.5) and
                A_ML < (15.5 + 0.5) and
                A_ML > (15.5 - 0.5) 
            order by
                sqrt(power((A_FX - 47.7),2) + 
                    power((A_ML - 15.5),2))
            limit 1
     )
join OF_MNTAB
    on (OF_MNTAB.OFID = OFTAB.OFID)
    where 
        DATEI <= getdate() and
        DATEF >= getdate() and
        OFTAB.FLAGD = 0 and
        CODE not in ('MANU','TRAN') and
        VENDOR = A_COD
    order by DATEI desc
```

but it keeps giving me errors when i try to execute it:
syntax error near "limit" and if i delete the limit option it gives me syntax error near join in the next line..
i am an sql noob and this is a complicated query for me..
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: MySQL? Oracle? SQL-Server? Not all DBMS have `LIMIT`

Comment: Adaptive Server Anywhere

Comment: I think that you can use `SELECT TOP 1 ...` (`TOP` is a Sybase / SQL-Server extension to SQL) instead of the `LIMIT 1` (which is a MySQL extension.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot use limit inside subquery. And you missed alias for the inline view

```
Select VENDOR, CODE, TABOF.OFID,DATEI,DATEF,VARR,VARRT,DESEXT
from (
        Select A_IND,A_COD,A_DES,A_FX,A_ML,
               OFID,DATEI,DATEF,VARR,VARRT,FLAGD,VENDOR
        from ANTAB
        join TABOF
            on (ANTAB.A_COD = TABOF.VENDOR) 
            where
                A_FX <> '' and A_ML <> '' and 
                A_DES <> '' and A_COD <> '' and
                A_IND <> '' and
                A_FX < (47.7 + 0.5) and
                A_FX > (47.7 - 0.5) and
                A_ML < (15.5 + 0.5) and
                A_ML > (15.5 - 0.5) 
            order by
                sqrt(power((A_FX - 47.7),2) + 
                    power((A_ML - 15.5),2))

     ) OFTAB
join OF_MNTAB
    on (OF_MNTAB.OFID = OFTAB.OFID)
    where 
        DATEI <= getdate() and
        DATEF >= getdate() and
        OFTAB.FLAGD = 0 and
        CODE not in ('MANU','TRAN') and
        VENDOR = A_COD
    order by DATEI desc
```

Comment: Is this an SQL Anywhere limitation (not able to use `LIMIT` in subqueries)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Adaptive Server Anywhere SQL User’s Guide](http://download.sybase.com/pdfdocs/awg0902e/dbugen9.pdf), page 251, you can use `TOP`, not `LIMIT`. So, remove the `LIMIT 1` and add `TOP 1`:

```
Select VENDOR, CODE, TABOF.OFID,DATEI,DATEF,VARR,VARRT,DESEXT
from (
        Select TOP 1
               A_IND,A_COD,A_DES,A_FX,A_ML,
               OFID,DATEI,DATEF,VARR,VARRT,FLAGD,VENDOR
...
```

There is also an alias missing, as @chetan correctly pointed.